# Using the answer for the derivative of a function to get the answer of the integration of the same function

Tags: integration

I wanted to know how to get the answer using part (i) in this question without using integral by parts.

Q. i) Find (dy/dx) of y = $$e^{-2x}(x)$$

I got this as $$e^{-2x}(-2x) + e^{-2x} $$

Q. ii) Using your answer in (i), find:

$$∫e^{-2x}(x)$$

I equated u as -2x and got dx as (du/-2). I put x as (-u/2) and I got $$\frac{1}{4}∫e^{u}(u)$$

I am not so sure what to do after this. I wanted to know what could be done to get the answer without using integration by parts and only using the answer from part (i).

Comment: Using the answer from part (i) **is** integration by parts!

Comment: So is it not possible to maybe substitute anything from part (i) into part (ii) like for example putting (−2)^(−2) in place of ^() and doing something after that like seeing the similarity between the answer in part (i) and part (ii) and replacing something else?

Answer (score 1):

You have that 
$$
\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(e^{-2x}\cdot x\right)=e^{-2x}(-2x) + e^{-2x}
$$
Now integrating both sides with respect to $x$ we get
$$
e^{-2x}\cdot x=\int e^{-2x}(-2x)dx+\int e^{-2x}dx 
\\=-2\int e^{-2x}\cdot x - \dfrac{1}{2}e^{-2x} + C
$$
So with ended with 
$$
\int xe^{-2x}dx=-\dfrac{1}{4}e^{-2x}-\dfrac{1}{2}e^{-2x}\cdot x + C
$$

Comment: I'm not so sure how you integrated both the sides with respect to x (is it through integration by parts?)

Comment: No, it is not integration by parts. you're using the result from part (i), then you use (for the left part of the equation) the fundamental theorem of calculus (the Barrow's rule) and for the right side you have the integral that you need and the other one it's an immediate integral

Comment: Oh ok, thank you!

Comment: This is how integration by parts is derived, so in that sense it's equivalent to integration by parts. And it's not the fundamental theorem of calculus (which has to do with *definite* integrals), it's just the fact that (by definition) taking antiderivatives is the same thing as differentiating backwards.

Comment: How did you get the last line (did you multiply -2 to everything inside the integral)? I didn't exactly understand that part.

Comment: @HansLundmark you're right... they are different concepts... And yes is the same idea but I didn't use integration by parts, I just followed the idea.

Comment: @V11 I don´t understand the question. I multiplied the equation by $-1/2$ to have in the right side of the equation, the integral that we needed and then I passed the rest of the terms to the left side.